# Python: How to Loop Values in Table in same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have  A table that has two columns, the first containing the URLs, and the second containing numbers.

What I need to do is parsing  all URLs at the same time, then wait for how much in column 2, Then back again to parse each URL in column 1.
Not one by one but at the same time.

| URls | time for wait |
| --- | --- |
| url1 | 2 |
| url2 | 4 |
| url3 | 5 |

Thanks For helping,

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "parsing all URLs at the same time"?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried simple [multiprocessing](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html)?

Comment: I mean access all urls in the same time not one by One.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of the lists will be same and the time to wait values will match with the url you want you can do this to combine them.

```
urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.apple.com', 'https://www.duckduckgo.com']
time_to_wait = [2, 4, 5]

for url, wait_time in zip(urls, time_to_wait):
    get(url)
    sleep(wait_time)
```

I would checkout asyncio event loops to make them run at the same time.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html